# Is there a domain_hint or login_hint to go directly to passwordless email IdP?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using a passwordless email custom policy very similar to this: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless.xml#L16

Is there a way to set a `domain_hint` or a `login_hint` to tell /authorize endpoint to go directly to passwordless email IdP in my user journey?

For example `/authorize?domain_hint=facebook.com` will take my user directly to the Facebook login.